# Ubuntu: problem of display but cannot install Nvidia driver (login loop)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I come from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926976/ubuntu-login-loop-issue-nvidia-gtx-950m) and struggled a lot. But so I "solved" the login loop issue by going back to graphic "nouveau" driver. When I try to install a nvidia driver (370, 381), the login loop issue is back.

But now, with the "nouveau" driver, the display is awful. Very very slow.

How can I fix that ? Thanks for helping

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same issue(or symptoms). You might have an issue with permissions on the .Xauthority-file in your home directory. Also, if you are going to use the nvidia-drivers - you should uninstall the nouveau-driver(s).

Log in to a shell (Alt+Ctrl+F1) and `chown youruser:yourgroup .Xauthority` Also, check permissions on .Xauthority. They should be `-rw-------`.

Also, creating a new user and logging into it will most likely give you a working xsession.